# Php not returning data to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This is my ajax call:

```
 var urlstring = '/search/';

      $.ajax({

       url: urlstring+'model.php',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'text',
       'data': 'test=1',

       error: function(xhr, status, error) {

           console.debug(error);
       },

       success: function() {

         console.log('success');
       },

       complete: function(data) {

         console.log('complete');
         console.debug(data);
       }

     });
```

When I change `dataType: 'json'`, I get this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data Stack trace:
>   jQuery.parseJSON@http://localhost/search/js/vendor/jquery.js:7964:9
>   ajaxConvert@http://localhost/search/js/vendor/jquery.js:8246:19
>   done@http://localhost/search/js/vendor/jquery.js:8707:15
>   .send/callback/<@http://localhost/search/js/vendor/jquery.js:9123:9

I returned the data from php like this for json type:

```
json_encode($data);
```

I also tried setting the header before returning data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Now I tried changing `dataType: 'text'`:

In php file,

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

class SearchModel extends Database
{

    public $searchModel = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();

    }

    public function fetchLocations()
    {

        $query = array();
        $query[] = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_location`";

        $query = implode(' ', $query);

        $statement = self::$connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();

        $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $data;
    }
}

$searchModel = new SearchModel();
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {

    $data = $searchModel->fetchLocations();
    // header('Content-Type: application/json');
    return  $data;
}
?>
```

The data not received by my ajax call. I found that, `success` was executing first before calling the php file. I set async:false, to no avail.

Then I added `complete` below `success` and this time I saw ajax was getting something else than the data I'm expecting from the server:

> Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:
>   .ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders:
>   .ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader:
>   .ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType:
>   .ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(),
>   abort: .ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: .Deferred/promise.state(), always:
>   .Deferred/promise.always(), then: .Deferred/promise.then(), 11 more… }

Comment: you need to echo the data, not return. the js is reading an external file after all

Comment: tried echo, but still I don't get the data form server but this: Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: .Deferred/promise.state(), always: .Deferred/promise.always(), then: .Deferred/promise.then(), 12 more… }

Comment: @nogad, I checked in the network tab, it shows the correct json string. however it's not passed to ajax call. I suspect something wrong with it. The url given is correct.

Comment: @nogad, I got the data in success rather than complete. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to 
`echo json_encode($data);` in order to send data to the XHR request. Just `return` will not work

Answer (score 0):

**replace**

`return $data;`

**with this**

`echo json_encode($data);`

`json_encode` will convert your array in json encoded string, then in JavaScript you can parse data using `$.parseJSON(data)`.

we use **`echo`** not  **`return`** when using ajax.